# How do I delete all lines in a file until it matches a string line pattern?

Tags: text-processing, sed, python, perl

How can I delete lines in a file until it matches a string line pattern?

```
cat test.txt
The first line
The second line
The third line
The fourth line
pen test/ut
The sixth line
The seventh line
```

I would like to use shell/python script to remove all the lines from the above file until it matches the file string pattern "pen test"

Expected output: The file "test.txt" should have only these lines after removing above lines:

```
The sixth line
The seventh line
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in python scripting?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed: delete everything up to the first match and modify the file in-place:

```
sed -i '0,/pen test/d' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
cat test.txt | grep -A2 "pen test/ut" | sed "1 d"
The sixth line
The seventh line
```

Comment: This assumes that you already know what the content of the file is. In that case, why don't you simply run `tail -n 2 infile` to get the last two lines instead of using  three commands, pipes etc ?

Comment: @don_crissti . thanks! I am a newbie I still have 304 reputations, give me thumb up ;-)

Comment: Your answers will be upvoted when they are valid. We don't rate people, we rate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use utilities `sed` and `Perl` to do this as follows:

```
perl -ne '
  next unless /pen/;  #  skip till we meet the first interesting record
  print <>;           # <> in the list context, fetches the entire remaining file
' input-file.txt

sed -ne '
   /pen/!d
   n
   :loop
      $!N;P;s/.*\n//
   tloop
' input-file.txt

sed -ne '
   /pen/!d  ;# reject lines till we see the first interesting line
   n        ;# skip the first time we see the interesting line
   :n       ;# then setup a do-while loop which"ll do a print->next->print->... till eof
      p;n   ;# the looping ends when the n command tries to read past the last record
   bn
' input-file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
perl -ni.bck -e '$i++,next if /^pen test/;print if $i' file
```

This reads your input file and does an in-place update. The original file is preserved with a `.bck` suffix extension.

As each line of the file is read, a flag, `$i`, is set if a line begins with `pen test` and the next line is read. When `$i` isn't zero (a true condition), lines are printed.

If you only want to extract the lines of interest, and not update, simply do:

```
perl -ne '$i++,next if /^pen test/;print if $i' file
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing a response with a shell script using split and sed, I remembered the shell command csplit (context split).

I saved your text above in /tmp/del.me. The command:

```
csplit del.me "/pen test/"
```

splits the original file into two files, one with the text before the match, the other with the text including and following.

```
host:tmp me$ cat xx01
pen test/ut
The sixth line
The seventh line
```

If you don't want the match, you can add "+1" to the match argument and it puts the matched text in the first file.

```
csplit del.me "/pen test/+1"
```

So, the above command gives me two output files xx00 xx01. (You can change the file naming.) xx01 contains:

```
host:tmp me$ cat xx01
The sixth line
The seventh line
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in python scripting?